# Wildfly Security Manager : Permission failed for javax.management.MBeanPermission

Tags: wildfly-10, java-security, javapolicy

I have My JBOSS Wildfly10 set up. I am enabling SECMGR flag in standlone.conf.bat file to true for enabling java security manager and as my war is deployed in wildfy 10 ,I am giving following permission set in standalone.xml as below and getting following error:

> 14:49:56,804 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58)
>   2017-03-28 14:49:56,804 ServerService Thread Pool -- 58 ERROR Could
>   not unregister MBeans for org.apac
>   he.logging.log4j2:type=2483b420,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer
>   java.security.AccessControlException: WFSM000001: Permission check
>   failed (permission "( "javax.management.MBeanPermission" "-#-[-]"
>   "queryNames")" in code source
>   "(vfs:/C:/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/mySample.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.5.
>   jar )" of "null")

My Standalone.xml configuration is as below so please can anyone help me out here where I am doing wrong ?

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
                <deployment-permissions>
                    <minimum-set>
                        <permission class="java.lang.RuntimePermission" name="shutdownHooks"/>
                        <permission class="java.util.PropertyPermission" name="*" actions="read"/>
                        <permission class="java.lang.RuntimePermission" name="createClassLoader"/>
                        <permission class="java.lang.RuntimePermission" name="getClassLoader"/>
                        <permission class="java.lang.RuntimePermission" name="shutdownHooks"/>
                        <permission class="javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" name="createMBeanServer"/>
                        <permission class="java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" name="suppressAccessChecks"/>
                        <permission class="javax.management.MBeanPermission" name="registerMBean"/>
                        <permission class="javax.management.MBeanPermission" name="queryNames"/>
                    </minimum-set>
                </deployment-permissions>
            </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queryNames` and `registerMBean` permissions aren't quite right. The `name` attribute should be the name of the MBean. The `registerMBean`and `queryNames` are actions.

It should probably look something like:

```
<permission class="javax.management.MBeanPermission" name="*" actions="registerMBean"/>
<permission class="javax.management.MBeanPermission" name="*" actions="queryNames"/>
```

You can specify the specific names or just use `*` as a wildcard. Have a look at the [`MBeanPermission`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanPermission.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hi James thanks for reply, I am little new to java security management as you said I have corrected the permission and referred the MBeanPermission link , It was helpful for me and that issue got fixed.